# Google Sheets Add row based on cell number value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, insert, row, google-apps

I'm trying to make a google sheet script that adds a row based on cell value, basically if I have in the Quantity (Column D) 7x laptops, I want the script to add 6 additional rows below if Column H is marked as "Yes" through data validation.

What I was able to find and to do is only duplicate that row but is without data validation and I would prefer to add the data validation and possible make each quantity split to 1 (instead of 7) after the duplication.

```
`function autoDup() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
     var newData = [];
     for(var n in data){
       newData.push(data[n]);
    if(!Number(data[n][3])){continue};// if column 3 is not a number then do nothing
      for(var c=1 ; c < Number(data[n][3]) ; c++){ // start from 1 instead of 0 because we have already 1 copy
      newData.push(data[n]);//store values
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData).sort({column: 1, ascending: false});// write new data to sheet, overwriting old data
}`
```

Hope someone is able to help me.
Thank you,

Comment: Welcome. Just to clarify... is the number of additional rows that you want to add equal to "the quantity in Column D" minus one (such as seven minus one = six)? And the content of Column D is it consistently structured as "abcd" when "a" = qty (an integer value), b="x" c="a space" and d = the product, expressed as a plural noun which may or may not contain spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column D contains a qty and goods description. If Column H = "Yes", you want to insert a number of rows below Col D equal to the qty minus one. If Column H <> "Yes, then take no action.

---

**Sample data - Before**

[image: Sample data before]

---

**Sample data - After**

[image: Sampledataafter]

---

```
function so5925663201() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "59256632";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  var row = 7;

  // get value of Column H
  var colHValue = sheet.getRange(row,8).getValue();

  if (colHValue === "Yes"){
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: Col H = yes. do something")

    // get value of Column D
    var Value = sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue();
    var searchterm = "x";
    var indexOfFirst = Value.indexOf(searchterm);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the first instance of 'x' is "+indexOfFirst);

    // get the quantity and convert from a string to a number
    var qty = Value.substring(0, indexOfFirst);
    var qtynum = +qty;
    // var newtype = typeof qtynum; // DEBUG
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the quantity is "+qtynum+", new type = "+newtype)

    // This inserts rows after 
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(row, qtynum-1);
  }
  else{
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: col H <> Yes. do nothing");
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this script activate once an user selects "Yes" in the drop-down in the sheet? And make the script copy  a few info below when inserting the new rows? Like "Dell Laptops"?

Comment: Also, another quick question, I have the quantity of the items in a separate column formatted as number. I can leave out the "searchterm" variable and leave out the conversion from a string to a number, is that correct? Also Thank you very much for helping me out on this, I'm pretty new to Java Script, for allot of time I thought that google sheets scripts also work with VBA lol.

Comment: I had a feeling that there was more to this scenario than described in the question... yes, you can leave out the search term and conversion. There are several options for triggers, it depends a lot on the number of users, frequency of editing, etc. some options are ‘onEdit’, a custom menu, or a button that triggers a script.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I thought that I wasn't really clear with my scenario.

Comment: You can certainly fill the empty rows; again there are options, not just to fill column D, but also if you want/expect to fill other columns too. You might also want (and this is taking things to another level) to group the rows- so, 7xlaptops expands to display the other rows. My suggestion is that now that you know you can insert the rows, give some thought to the package of outcomes that you want to achieve rather than adding things piecemeal.

Comment: Well the frequency of editing will be really high and allot of number of users will edit the sheet (though I'm not expecting a high number of users to edit at the same time). When you mean "onEdit" it means it will activated the script once the cell is changed from blank to something? I saw that it's possible to draw a button and attach the function to it for the script to be activated, do you know if it can also be added to all cells to a specific column?

Comment: onEdit is triggered by "every" edit, though you put logic in the script to test whether the edited cell was in Column H and whether the edited cell had a value of "Yes", then (and only then) would the rest of the script execute. But if you have a lot of edits, then onEdit is running all the time; The button-triggered code might be better. Either way (and this is important), you need to do something to "turn Column H off", otherwise it will keep inserted rows ad infinitum. "if it can also be added to all cells to a specific column?" not sure what that means.